# Android: Fragment retain instance memory management

Tags: android, garbage-collection, fragment

im wondering how androids garbage collector works with data that is kept by the fragment (retain instance).

If I have a Class hirarchy like this:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

      private DataManager dataManager;

      public MyFragment(){
            setRetainInstance(true);
      }


      public void onCreate(){
           if (dataManager == null)
           dataManager = new DataManager();

           dataManager.setView(this);
      }


      public void onCreateView(){
          // display the data of the dataManager
      }


      public void onStop(){
           dataManager.setView(null);
      }
  }


class DataManager implements DataChangedListener {

     private MyFragment view;
     private Data data;


     public DataManager(){

            data.setDataChangedListener(this);

     }


     public void setView(MyFragment v){
          this.view = v;          
      }

 }


 class Data {

      public void setDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l){
           this.listener = l;
      }
 }
```

So what i want to do is, that on `orientation` change the fragments view content will be recreatd. But the underlying data (`DataManager` and Data) must not reload.
The `DataManager` listen to the Data Object for changes, an will forward this changes to the UI, the `Fragment`. `Fragment` is "attached" to the `DataManager` when its (re)created.

So far so good. It seems to me a good Solution and well structured. Basically its some kind of Model-View-Presenter pattern.

But now im wondering, when Android will run the garbage collector to collect the `DataManager` and Data Objects.

Assume I have an Activity that displays `MyFragment`.

But what happens to the memory, when the user of the App navigates to another Activity, that displays something completely different.

Since there is a reference from `DataManager` to Data and vice versa, I guess that the data will be kept "forever" in memory, right?
So I guess the garbage collector will only remove this both when the device is going on low memory. But I guess, that these two objects would not be automatically the first two data objects that were garbage collected. I guess there is some kind of "memory deadlock".

What do you think? Any suggestions?

Comment: To avoid such leaks you can use WeakReference: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Garbage Collector:**

I might be wrong on some concepts here but, as far as I know, the Garbage collector starts from a known object and "navigates" down the object tree, if any object is not on that tree, it will be collected.

So for example, it stats from the activity, and it have references to a few views, an adapter, and to the FragmentManger, the FragmentManager have reference to a 3 fragments, those fragments to a few data objects, and so on.

But if Object_A have ref to Object_B and Object_B to Object_A but no one else have reference to Object_A or Object_B, you can kiss good bye to those two.

**Suggestion:**

Usually to simplify the whole `setRetainInstance(true);` deal, I make a rule for myself (remember, that's not obligatory, but it does make life easier to understand and abstract): That if I want/need to retain data and will use `setRetainInstance` that one fragment does not have a view. That means, I do not override it's `onCreateView` and the transaction on it it's a simple `add(mFrag, MyFrag.TAG);`, not placing it anywhere in layouts.

That simplifies because you know that all the views are re-created when needed and you can always access your data using `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyFrag.TAG);`

And back to the GC deal, with that approach you know that your data will not be GCed because it's safely kept by the FragmentManager.

sounds like a good plan? what do u think?

**edit:**

**Further suggestion:**

do not keep any reference to any View, or Activity, or Context in your DataFragment. Any long living object should not keep those references as they do hold the whole activity and that's a huge memory leak.

Comment: Thank you! I added some more code to my fragment code. What I want to do is, to handle the orientation change without loosing/reloading data. But when I finish the activity, e.g. by starting another activity, I want to ensure, that the data can be collected by the GC. So when I left the Activity that holds the fragment, there are reference between DataManager and Data. No other reference. It's like you have described above and you guess it can be GCed. Are you sure about it, or is it a guess?  A word to your tipp of how you handle setRetainInstance().I dont understand it. Can you explain it?

Comment: check on your examples on \\sdk\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos\src\com\example\android\supportv4\app\FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.Java. That what I mean. Check that fragment that do work, and hold data doesn't have "onCreateView"